# What references to Diablo II characters exist in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-series

I'm a huge fan of Diablo's lore and was happy to see many of the characters from the original game show up in Diablo III. However, it doesn't seem like there are very many references to Diablo II characters besides the ones in the main questline. So far, I've found:

> Warriv's corpse in a random event with a little lore book

But not very much else.

Are there other allusions and references to, or appearances of, Diablo II characters in Diablo III?

Comment: There are tons of references to the Iron Wolves......Finish all of the Acts and be sure to pick up all the lore books.

Comment: Regarding your second bit of spoilered text: play the game through to completion. He's very much present.

Comment: Someone edited my text so now it says there is no mention of them... I said there is and wanted to know who, besides Tyrael and the Ironwolves (obvious mainquest references) is there..

Comment: This is little more than "What eastereggs are there in Diablo 3?" in a different skin. Closing, as per site policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've found:

- Mentions of the Evils, like Andy and Mephisto
- Deckard Cain, of course
- Tyrael
- Mentions that the heroes from Diablo II have gone mad
- Wirt's in the game, or at least his bell
- References to the "cow level"
- The mad king of tristram
- The dark wonderer from DII
- Andrea (gives you the den of evil quest in DII)
  (these are what i've found agian so far)
- A quest from a necromancer in act 2 that mentions he was trained by the necromancer hero in d2.
- Gharbads ghost gives you a quest.
- In old tristram griswolds shop sign can still be read.

Comment: you mean Andariel right :)

Comment: With the D1 hero getting possessed and D2 heroes going mad - I wonder what happens to the D3 crowd when we get Diablo 4!

Comment: WRT: Asheara, a guard in D3's act2 (the one who opens the palace): isn't she the one where you can hire followers in D2's act2?

Comment: If you have an issue with a question being closed, please raise it by opening a question on our [meta] site.

Comment: it's not `Andrea`, it's `Akara` :) And `Adria` is a witch from Diablo 1 who was selling magic stuff